# in Ruby, how do I write array elements into txt file such that each element is on a separate line?

Tags: ruby, file, iteration, each, element

I am having difficulty in writing array elements into a text file in the form of 1 element per line. In this instance array is built on sentences (.) .

Please see comments in code below:

```
puts "enter paragraph:"
para = gets.chomp.to_s
my_array = []

para.split('.').each { |p| my_array << p+ '.'; print "pushed #{p}.";puts}
new_text = File.new("new_text.txt", "w+")
p my_array
my_array.each { |m| new_text.write(m)} #clearly iterating over my_array.
#.each should be writing each element on a different line, no?  Where have I gone wrong?
new_text.seek(0)

#text file is still stored in new_text variable
#the read out shows elements are not written per line
line = 1
new_text.each do |n|
    puts "line #{line}: #{n}"
    line += 1
    end
```

Comment: One way to write each element (a string) of an array `arr` to a file, one line per element, is `File.write(filename, arr.join("\n"))`.

Answer (score 3):

`.each should be writing each element on a different line? no`

No, whether you're iterating over something does not really matter. What matters is how you're writing into the file.

Currently you're using [IO#write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/IO.html#method-i-write) which doesn't say anything about adding newlines. If you change `new_text.write` to `new_text.puts` ([IO#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/IO.html#method-i-puts)) you will be writing a new line after each element from your array.

You can easily see it by using `$stdout` directly:

```
> a = %w(foo bar)
 => ["foo", "bar"] 
> a.each(&$stdout.method(:write)) # write -- no newlines
foobar => ["foo", "bar"] 
> a.each(&$stdout.method(:puts))  # puts  -- newlines
foo
bar
 => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: my mistake. I have removed faulty question.

Comment: Also, notably, `new_text.puts(my_array)` will do exactly what you want, even without any explicit loop - `puts` prints arrays with one line per row by default.